# Which Java version check

Tags: java, cmd

For a company (1000+ employees) we want to check if everyone has the latest Java installed (build 1.7.0_51-b13). If the user doesn't have the latest version of Java, the user is notified to update his Java version.

In a script it is possible to run "java -version", but Java is not always in the system variables. To find out where Java is installed, the script has to check which Windows the user is running. This can be XP, Windows 7 or 8. But I am a bit stuck, as I think there should be a better and easier solution to this.

Comment: Wouldn't the latest version of Java be Java 8? :p

Comment: You could just say that if the path isn't configured then Java isn't properly configured? You may get better answers on this one in Super User as its more about system configuration/shell scripts/etc than programming.

Comment: Doesn't java already notify people if it's out of date?

Comment: Also, this should be on super user.

Answer (score 2):

What I would probably do is create a *java program* to do the check, so that the path variable doesn't matter. Try something like

```
public class Checker {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String[] version = System.getProperty("java.version").split("\\."); // it's regex so we have to escape it
        int first=Integer.parseInt(version[0]);
        int second=Integer.parseInt(version[1]); // the property is in the form x.x.x
        if(first==1 && second < 7){ // check for less than 1.7.x, modify this to suit your needs, I would change it to 1.8.x as soon as official java 8 is released
            // prompt to update
        }
    }
}
```

Then just compile it as a jar and distribute it. This is of course assuming that people have *some version* of java in the first place, but I'm assuming they do from your question.

Answer (score 0):

It is much more complicated. JAVA_HOME might be set differently than the PATH, and which is worse, JRE installation likes copying JAVA.EXE to `C:\Windows\System32` folder, which JDK installation does not do. So you may end up with JAVAC.EXE and JAVA.EXE running from command line each from a different version. I guess that in the `C:\Windows\System32` folder you have those EXE files from the last launched JRE installation, but they are not necessarily those which will run if you just write JAVA.EXE.

So it is not enough knowing that you have the latest version installed, but you need to ensure that your application will be launched using the proper Java version. Some application have the JAva version in their configuration file, e.g. in Eclipse.ini.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Regedit /e \\gaia\%USERDOMAIN%.reg HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft
```

And parse the files. Whearat gaia is your networkdrive.

The file will contains entries like this:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft]
"RegDeployStatus"="0"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Development Kit]
"CurrentVersion"="1.5"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Development Kit\1.5]
"JavaHome"="C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.5.0_22\\"
"MicroVersion"="0"
```

Comment: I hope you have DHCP with Domains to call `LOGONSCR.cmd` automatically.